# How to use one Qscrollbar for two QListWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, scrollbar

I want to scroll in two different `QListWidgets` simultaneously by using only one `QScrollBar`. One way could be to connect the `QScrollBar` `changeValue()` Signal to both `QListWidgets`, but I don't know how to do it.

Different solutions are welcome too (but there must be two `QListWidgets`)

GUI Example

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't know how to do it"? It works just like any other Qt signal connection: someObject.someSignal.connect(otherObject.otherSignal). Also, the signal is `valueChanged` (not `changeValue`) which is the signal for the [`value`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) property. Just connect each signal with the opposite function. If you don't know how signals and slots connection work, I strongly urge you to read [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a minimal reproducible example or at least an attempt. Here more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to connect the `valueChanged` signal of the scroll bar of one list widget to `setValue` method of the another list widget's scrollbar. Doing so will scroll the second list widget whenever the first list widget is scrolled.

You need to do this for both the list-widgets so that scrolling of any list widget scrolls the other.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QListWidget, QApplication


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.list1.addItems(['Asia Pacific',  'Europe', 'Middle East', 'Africa', 'America']*5)
        self.list2.addItems(['AP', 'EU', 'ME',  'AF', 'AM']*5)
        self.list1.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.\
            connect(self.list2.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.list2.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.\
            connect(self.list1.verticalScrollBar().setValue)

    def setupUI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.list1 = QListWidget(self)
        self.list2 = QListWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list1)
        layout.addWidget(self.list2)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```